# Reversed graph plotting algorithm

Tags: functions

Consider a real-valued polynomial function of one variable. Knowing the "rules" function dictates we can plot the graph of that function with a given accuracy.

Question: is the reversed process possible?

Comment: You mean, given a graph, can you get the function?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: well, you kind of have to specify what you're willing to admit as a "function", otherwise you'd just say $f(x)$ is the unique $x$ mapping to the appropriate point. if you restrict what class of functions you're considering the graph of you can get a "better" answer i guess, like if you restrict to polynomials

Comment: Changed the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the "rule-based" part of your comment, if you demand perfect accuracy, the answer is no.  Just take any curve that goes through $(0,y)$ at an in[definable real number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number).  If you accept some error in both directions, you can use an interpolating polynomial of high enough degree.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.arachnoid.com/sage/polynomial.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression

Comment: As far as I understand, no. The question can also be posed like this: let's assume I've drawn an arbitrary graph in Paint. Does three exist a symbolic, "rule-like" representation of the function this graph presumably represents?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, beside the graph, you have a table with some values $(x,f(x))$. In some cases, say equispaced $x$ points, building a finite difference table should allow to guess the degree of the polynomial and, subsequently, to compute the coefficients by interpolation. If you *know* that the data is produced by a polynomial, then iterative regressions (or interpolations) with different polynomial specifications *must* ultimately estimate the right coefficients giving null error up to roundoff.

More generally, symbolic regression may help, see http://www.ams.org/notices/201306/rnoti-p713.pdf for an interesting description of a software that can guess the symbolic form of your function. You can specify the search space to include only "+" and "*" (sum and product), effectively reducing the search to polynomials.

The software can be downloaded at http://formulize.nutonian.com/ and a serious treatment appeared on Science, http://www.sciencemag.org/content/324/5923/81.abstract